# How to set SBT default log level to "warn"?

Tags: scala, logging, default, sbt

default SBT log level is info (see http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningSbt).

How do I set it to warn as the default?

---

@Christian: Thanks! Did you get that to work? I modified the sbt.boot.properties accordingly and passed it via:

(1) -Dsbt.boot.properties=mysbt.boot.properties

(2) -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.7.7/libexec/sbt-launch-0.7.7.jar "@/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.7.7/libexec/mysbt.boot.properties"

Both ways process my sbt.boot.properties but I still see [info] log messages. [Overriding project settings](http://simple-build-tool.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/latest/sxr/sbt/BuilderProject.scala.html) does not work either.

I wonder if this works at all. I even found a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/issues/detail?id=168).

Thanks,
Lars

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17016028/1305344

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define it in sbt.boot.properties as explained here: [sbt wiki](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/GeneralizedLauncher)

Comment: Hey Christian, please give me a hint how you did it. I wanna give you the bounty!!! :-)

Comment: OK, I will give you the bounty anyway. But please post how you solved the issue!

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. I read it in the docs and assumed it works. But I have the same problem (I'm using 0.7.5).

Answer (score 9):

You can set it temporarily by prefixing your action with `warn`, eg

```
~> sbt warn compile
```

or from the sbt console:

```
~> sbt
[info] Building project test 1.0 against Scala 2.8.1
[info]    using TestProject with sbt 0.7.7 and Scala 2.7.7
> warn
Set log level to warn
> compile
>
```

Comment: Thanks Kristian, but I already use that method and I don't want to set the log level every time I restart sbt.

Comment: this no longer works with xsbt. Is there an answer to that? I do want to set the log level from the command line, as it is very useful to switch.

Comment: I used this on sbt 0.7.5, it says "Set log level to warn" but then I get tons of DEBUG and INFO messages. Is this a bug of SBT? or do the messages come from somewhere else (I'm using Lift).

Answer (score 7):

In XSBT this seems to be the way to do it from the console

```
set logLevel in run := Level.Debug
```

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Quick-Configuration-Examples

Note that these are SBT levels, so for example they don't work directly with Play 2.0!