# How to change log level from command line?

Tags: sbt

How can I change the log level in sbt at the command line without modifying the existing configuration?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As described in [Change the logging level globally](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Logging.html#Change+the+logging+level+globally) for sbt:

> To set the logging level before any commands are executed on startup,
>   use -- before the logging level

There are four logging levels:

- debug
- info
- warn
- error

If you need one applied *"at the command line without modifying the existing configuration"*, execute the `sbt` launcher with appropriate level prefixed with double dashes.

```
jacek:~/oss/scalania
$ sbt --debug
[debug] > boot
[debug] > reload
[debug] > sbtStashOnFailure
[debug] > onFailure load-failed
[debug] > loadp
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[debug] Running task... Cancelable: false, check cycles: false
[debug]
```

With `sbt.boot.properties` you may get `sbt` internal logs printed out, too. See [Launcher Specification](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html).

Comment: I used `sbt --info test` but it still logs at debug level.

Answer (score 11):

For SBT 0.12:

If you want to change the log level from the command line, you may do in sbt interactive mode without changing your build.sbt file or any configuration. Just type:

```
> set logLevel := Level.Debug
```

However if you are writing some scripts that will run in your server and you can't do interactively, you will have to create a boot.properties file setting the desired log level and pass this file in the command line, by running

```
sbt -Dsbt.boot.properties=path-to-your-boot.properties
```

Check the documentation for boot.properties [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html)