# Change the sbt log level on only my machine in perpetuity?

Tags: scala, sbt

Every time I use `sbt` the first thing I do is set the log level to Error:

```
$ sbt
// ... sbt loads
[my_project] $ error
[my_project] $
```

Several places [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6189671/446554) and [elsewhere](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-set-sbt-logging-level-build.sbt/) recommend adding this to either your `build.sbt` or your `sbt.boot.properties`:

```
set logLevel in run := Level.Error
```

But I'm working in a shared project with many developers and I don't want to change the log level for *everyone*, just me! I do currently use `SBT_OPTS` to tailor sbt's memory usage on my machine, and this may potentially be an option but I can't find any guidance on what format to pass options via `SBT_OPTS` except for Java things like `pass -Dkey=val directly to the java runtime` and memory parameters like `-Xmx8G`.

`sbt --help` indicates that `.sbtopts` may also be a potential option:

```
  .sbtopts            if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                      are prepended to the runner args
```

But as far as I can tell there are no method to specify command-line "runner args" that set the log level to Error, only for setting the log level to debug via `--debug`.

I'm a little stumped, I've identified at least two potential avenues (`SBT_OPTS` and `.sbtopts`) for passing machine-specific customization to sbt, but do either of these support setting the log level to Error? Or is there a third avenue I'm missing, maybe some elusive `~/.sbt`, that I could use to set my machine's sbt log level to Error?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Logging.html#Change+the+logging+level+globally . Also, this line from `sbt --help` might help `/etc/sbt/sbtopts    if this file exists, it is prepended to the runner args`

Comment: >  maybe some elusive ~/.sbt, that I could use to set my machine's sbt log level to Error?

Yes, you can put your own custom configuration into `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt` (or `0.13` for sbt 0.13.x). See https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Global-Settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/global.sbt`

```
logLevel := Level.Error
```

All available log level options are:

- `Error`
- `Warn`
- `Info`
- `Debug`

<sub>Thanks @maxkar for leading me to this solution</sub>